# DownloadLink with an option to choose the directory where the file should be saved apache wicket

Tags: java, html, apache, download, wicket

this is my download link I did from the wicket example site. I would like to alter it by letting the user choose the directory the file should be saved. Any way to implement it? Thanks in advance

```
     add(new DownloadLink("generate_report", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<File>()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public File getObject()
        {
            File tempFile;
            try
            {
                tempFile = File.createTempFile("wicket-examples-download-link--", ".tmp");

                InputStream data = new ByteArrayInputStream("some data".getBytes());
                Files.writeTo(tempFile, data);

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return tempFile;
        }
    }).setCacheDuration(Duration.NONE).setDeleteAfterDownload(true));
```

Comment: No, as the placement of the file on the client's disc is the job of the browser which will open a dialog asking for the destination or using the default download-folder anyway.

Comment: how to "tell" the browser to open this dialog? this function saves it in default folder :(

Comment: The user is "telling" the browser to open the dialog by right clicking the link and chosing the aproriate option (labeles differently in different browsers). Otherwise the user is "telling" the browser to use the default download directory.

Comment: so I cannot force (right-click->Save file) to be triggered on left mouse click on button?

Comment: so there is none "FileUploadField-like" thing that works for downloading? :/

Comment: No, otherwise every hacker would happily choose to download his trojaned version of the file explorer to c:\windows\explorer.exe and own 95% percent of all windows based computers. Additionally the client just issues a request for 'that resource' without any information about what he's intending to do with it.

Comment: but user would have to choose this path in dialog window. He wouldn't have choosen windows directory. 
I don't know if U know what I mean. I want to http://www.pragsoft.com/umls/help/gifs/chap8/FileSaveAsDialog.gif this window to popup and then save the file in choosen directory.

Answer (score -1):

If you have preset paths then the user can choose which one they want to use by using the include_path function; however, the user will not be able to create their own directory/path.

EDIT:  Couldn't put code in that comment lol but here is where I was going at.

```
$path1=set_include_path('file\whateveryouwant');
```

Then you can use multiple paths and let the user choose from the paths by calling the $path1 (wich would be the extension for the path you want them to use). 
More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php

Comment: so there is no option to open a window  on click and manually choose the destination folder?
I found it for uploading files: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/upload/single?0 but I cant find an example for download

Comment: You can use the set_include_path to set the path that you want your users' to choose. Then you can use the get_include_path to retrive that set path.

Comment: Note that this is PHP and not Java.

Comment: @Nicktar Very true but since this is for a web page you can incorporate both languages very easily.

Comment: @Llama apart from the fact that it might be difficult to integrate a php generated link into a wicket generated page that generates the target on the fly, your answer doesn't adress the OPs question. It's not about including files or directories on the server but about download destinations on the client side which can't be done due to security implications and the way http works.